# Shared Database between 2 application instances in different servers

Tags: java, database, shared

Let me share our current setup first.

We have an application that runs on 2 servers (server A and B), and the purpose of having this is for load balancing purposes. The application version on both A and B are exactly the same and there is a shared database between 2 instances.

We are currently encountering an issue wherein it seems that stored values of variables are being shared between the two instances as well which is not what we expected.

For example, there is one configuration file in server A and another in server B. There are instances wherein the contents are different. What we have found is that sometimes when accessing the application in server A and then reading the configuration file, we are also getting values that are contained in the configuration file in server B.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue as we have? And any tips on how to get around this issue?

Regards,

Philip

Comment: are you building your properties file in jar or referring from outside of jar  ?

Comment: They are outside the jar, located on a folder in the server.

Comment: then its not atall possible that A can read B's prop file, i think you should debug your application locally, eclipse is real nice for that, second put lot of debug logger on server.

Comment: yes, it should not be possible. But after reading the file, the application stores the value into a variable. Is it possible that this variable is shared between the 2 instances since they share the same database?

Comment: no not atall possible, 2 instance of object in 2 different jvm running on 2 different servers can be conflict with each other in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) service, share your configuration between any number of instances you want

> etcd is a distributed, consistent key-value store for shared configuration and > service discovery, with a focus on being:
>   - Simple: curl'able user-facing API (HTTP+JSON)
>   - Secure: optional SSL client cert authentication
>   - Fast: benchmarked 1000s of writes/s per instance
>   - Reliable: properly distributed using Raft